# SQL - Multiple records in one row

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, concatenation

I've trying to create a script that allows me to display multiples records in a one-row, group by a specific column. Below is the code that I worked on. I've done it in Power BI but now I need it on SQL Someone could help me how can I fix this, I appreciate:

MY CODE:

```
   B.WorkOrderCode,
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + A.UserName 
          FROM [PanatrackerGP].[dbo].[User] AS A
          WHERE A.ProfileOid = B.ProfileOid
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [USERS]
FROM [PanatrackerGP].[dbo].[TrxIssueInventory] AS B
WHERE B.WorkOrderCode = 'S12119' 
GROUP BY B.ProfileOid, B.WorkOrderCode
ORDER BY 1

------------------------------  OUTPUT  ----------------------------------------

WorkOrderCode  |      USERS

S12119         |   GM; FM; FO; GR; RG; TI
S12119         |   NC; BS; DNA; CS; JMAGGI; mj; fa; LR; lgm; MS; JPU
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Only these users should be shown 

------------------------------TrxIssueInventory[TABLE]-----------------
WorkOrderCode |  CreateUserName

S12119        |      FO
S12119        |      lgm
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------GOAL OUTPUT---------------------------------
WorkOrderCode |  CreateUserName

S12119        |      FO ; lgm          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank You
```

Comment: What is your version of SQL Server?

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't concatenate anything, it only removes the leading separator. SQL Server 2017 introduced `STRING_AGG` to aggregate strings. Are you using an older version?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Good day, check this post [Unsplit Using For XML with group by columns](https://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/152/Unsplit-Using-For-XML-with-group-by-columns.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @RonenAriely, I followed the example of the page and it works out!

Comment: Obviously it will work. I published it only for you several years ago You are most welcome 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    STUFF(
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + CAST(CreateUserName AS VARCHAR (MAX))
            FROM [PanatrackerGP].[dbo].[TrxIssueInventory] 
            WHERE (WorkOrderCode = A.WorkOrderCode)
            FOR XML PATH ('')
            ),1,2,''
        ) AS [USERS]
FROM [PanatrackerGP].[dbo].[TrxIssueInventory] AS A
WHERE WorkOrderCode = 'S12119' 
GROUP BY WorkOrderCode

------------------OUTPUT-----------------------
WorkOrderCode     |       USERS
S12119            |      FO; lgm


Thank you all!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do an additional join within your correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  b.WorkOrderCode, 
        CreateUserName = STUFF((SELECT  CONCAT(';', u.UserName)
                                FROM    [dbo].[User] AS u
                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[TrxIssueInventory] AS i
                                            ON i.ProfileOid = u.ProfileOid
                                WHERE   i.WorkOrderCode = b.WorkOrderCode
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(1000)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    [dbo].[TrxIssueInventory] AS b
GROUP BY b.WorkOrderCode;
```

I've also amended your concatenation method slightly to use `FOR XML PATH(), TYPE` rather than just for XML path as this properly handles special XML Characters. If you had a username that was `LGM >` this would end up as `LGM &gt;`, if you don't use `TYPE` and '.value`.

**WORKING DEMO**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TrxIssueInventory', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TrxIssueInventory;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#User', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #User;

CREATE TABLE #TrxIssueInventory (WorkOrderCode INT, ProfileOid INT);
INSERT  #TrxIssueInventory VALUES (12119, 1), (12119, 2);

CREATE TABLE #User (ProfileOid INT, UserName VARCHAR(10));
INSERT #User VALUES (1, 'FO'), (2, 'LGM >');

SELECT  b.WorkOrderCode, 
        CreateUserName = STUFF((SELECT  CONCAT(';', u.UserName)
                                FROM    #User AS u
                                        INNER JOIN #TrxIssueInventory AS i
                                            ON i.ProfileOid = u.ProfileOid
                                WHERE   i.WorkOrderCode = b.WorkOrderCode
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(1000)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    #TrxIssueInventory AS B
GROUP BY b.WorkOrderCode;

-- DON'T USE, JUST HERE TO DEMONSTRATE THE ISSUE OF NOT USING 'TYPE'
SELECT  b.WorkOrderCode, 
        CreateUserName = STUFF((SELECT  CONCAT(';', u.UserName)
                                FROM    #User AS u
                                        INNER JOIN #TrxIssueInventory AS i
                                            ON i.ProfileOid = u.ProfileOid
                                WHERE   i.WorkOrderCode = b.WorkOrderCode
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM    #TrxIssueInventory AS B
GROUP BY b.WorkOrderCode
```

Comment: Thank you @GarethD, I appreciate the script. I might need for the next one coming up. I used JOIN and the TYPE before but I guess I structured it wrong. My mistake was not converting the DataType into VARCHAR.